# Qt TextBrowser Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt, qtextbrowser

How do I make a horizontal scrollbar appear whenever the application is resized so that every line is as appears? Sometimes, filenames are really long and I don't want to manually resize the form UI.

I have tried setting the scrollbar policy to as needed, but that doesn't do anything. Since the lines are still appearing on the screen.

[image]

Increasing size of form:

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set the [LineWrapMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#LineWrapMode-enum) to `QTextEdit::NoWrap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `QTextEdit::LineWrapMode` to `QTextEdit::NoWrap`.

```
ui->textBrowser->setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(QTextEdit::NoWrap); // or just '0'
```

See [class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#LineWrapMode-enum) for more details.